# Spring Framework NoSuchMethodFound Tomcat Error

Tags: grails, spring-security, intellij-idea, bamboo

I work on a 4 person development team using IntelliJ, but for some reason only one the team members can successfully build a WAR file and deploy. All other members will receive the following error:

> Aug 17, 2012 2:14:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   SEVERE: Error listenerStart
>   Aug 17, 2012 2:14:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>
> SEVERE: Context [/xxx] startup failed due to previous errors
>
> 2012-08-17 14:14:40,171 [http-8080-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironm
>   ent;

From everything I've researched, this is caused by a version conflict in the Spring Framework, but for the life of me I can't seem to resolve the issue.

Has anyone ever run into this issue? And how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your catalina.sh/catalina.bat such that you launch java using the `-verbose:class` flag.  It will produce a lot of output, but you should be able to see which JAR file you're loading `org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext` from and chances are it's not the same version that your version of Grails is using.  Remove the bad version from your classpath and hopefully you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yowza! Massive error in the stacktrace. So I attempted to take out the offending JAR files, but as soon as I created the WAR file they just started to install again.

`plugins.spring-security-core=1.2.4`

`plugins.spring-security-ldap=1.0.5`